# Callback function for asynch request

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

The below code gets a state from latitude/longitude coordinates.  How can I extract the value "result.body.region" from the scope of the anonymous function and use it in a higher scope?

```
latitude=tweets[0].latitude
longitude=tweets[0].longitude
var Request = unirest.get("https://montanaflynn-geocoder.p.mashape.com/reverse?latitude="+myobj.latitude+"&longitude="+myobj.longitude)
    .header("X-Mashape-Key", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
    .header("Accept", "application/json")
    .end(function (result) {

        state = result.body.region


  });
```

What I want to do is write a callback function that will wait for the asynch request to finish and use that information in a different scope.  I am self taught on javascript so I am struggling to understand callbacks.  How can I do this?

Comment: What you have will work. `state` will be a global variable (you might want to declare it specifically in the scope you want it in). Note that the variable will only have a value after the callback is executed.

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-04/async-method-patterns/

Answer (score 1):

The code you have already will do that.

You are probably trying to read the value of `state` before the callback has fired.

This is why we normally put the code to process the data in the callback: to make sure it runs after the asynchronous event has occurred.